# "The" or no article in this sentence

Tags: articles

> I woke up around ten, I made cup of coffee, and took it into **THE**
>   bedroom

Is using 'the' correct in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct. The word “bedroom” in this sense is referring to an actual thing, and must be preceded by “the.” In fact, I can’t think of an instance when “bedroom” wouldn’t take some kind of a determiner, such as ***that** bedroom, **our** bedroom, **a** bedroom*, etc.

In your example, “cup of coffee” also needs an article. In this case, it would be “**a** cup of coffee.”

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "an actual thing" ?

Comment: Meaning it refers to something established - your bedroom.